# Django use otp(One Time Password) to login instead of password

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using django-rest-framework to create login for a web app(frontend is in React), but I need to use only phone number and otp for login, no password. The otp is sent to the user's phone number. I am using a custom user model. I just cannot figure out how to override the built in login view. I am also trying to use jwt token auth using djangorestframework-simplejwt.

Please help me write this. 
models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.utils import timezone

from .managers import UserManager


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_fos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name', 'business_name']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

managers.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where phone number is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, phone, full_name, business_name, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given phone number.
        """
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError(_('Phone must be set'))
        user = self.model(phone=phone, full_name=full_name, business_name=business_name, **extra_fields)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone, full_name, business_name, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given phone number, name and buisness name.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(phone, full_name, business_name, **extra_fields)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for it?

Comment: Did you find solution yet?